# Realtime 1394 firewire video in a WPF app via directx or other method

Tags: wpf, video, directx, directshow, firewire

Are there any controls that anyone is aware of that I can use to stream firewire video into a WPF app.  I do not need camera control or capture just the video.  I need WPF hosting because I'll be adding WPF content on top.

I was hoping that with the addition of having direct X surfaces in WPF something like this might appear.

Ideally looking for something relatively high level (not a direct show guy at all).

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Hello Brian, can you give us any floowup to wour question? I took a look @RandomNickName42 answer, the last release of the "WPF Win32 render projec" dates 2007 ! So, it is not reliable becouse we don't know if one day they will fix the current bugs.

Comment: Pedro, we ended up using a different solution as the specs for that project changed. I recall determining that it was certainly possible using some 3rd party renderers (like the below links to Jeremiah's blog) but we ended up not needing to do it.

Comment: Oh... So, have you switched to another language like C++ or used a 3rth part app? Thanks for the update! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple really good video rendering packages for WPF.  This guy [Jeremiah Morrill](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/Default.aspx) has a [blog](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/Default.aspx) where he discusses his numerous render projects.  There's the WPF Win32 render project, and a number of low-level techniques he documents for how to access accelerated playback, Media Foundation .NET, DVD controls, etc... I believe his blog is titled "Jer's One Stop Shop".

Reading over his blog in general is a good idea if you are in to video/WPF.  Last I checked, "MediaKit", one of his more comprehensive projects, enables easy use of DirectShow (simple xaml and your off and running, so don't worry) and other well known native interfaces.  It's very robust and actively maintained, if not that specific project, check into some of the recent API's he's contributing on, some various Win7 media support also.

The only reason I'd bring up this other project, [Augmented Reality](http://www.mperfect.net/wpfAugReal/), is that you remarked about adding content "on top".  You should definitely check out wpfAugRel if your doing a lot of video production.  Where to get an add on for it eludes me, but I'm sure you can find it off that site, but it allows for you to script in python some fairly slick real-time video production.

-- edit --

Right, look at this [google code](http://sites.google.com/site/augmentedrealitytestingsite/) page, it has some video's (picture's worth a thousand words right?), but regardless, it allow's you to mix in 3D content into live-action, through the use of "marker" prop's, essentially bit's of paper with some easily machine recognizable feature's, that facilitate their underlying engine to inject computer rendered output into a real world scene, highly dynamic, so you can toss these marker's around and the 3D content move's fluidly...  anyhow good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/uberdemo/archive/2008/03/27/capturing-a-webcam-stream-to-a-wmv-file-from-within-a-wpf-application.aspx) by UberDemo.  It captures video into a WMV file with Windows Media Encoder and WPF.  There is a paragraph about how to do the preview in a WPF application.